# Ability to disable primeNG editor box

Tags: angular, primeng

It would be great if we could disabled the primeNG editor box with the disabled attribute, similar to what's available with a textarea :

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="10" disabled="disabled">
This textarea is grayed out and disabled for interaction.
</textarea>
```

But sadly that don't work. Do you have an idea on how can I do this with       p-editor (the primeNG editor)?

Answer (score 2):

`p-editor` is using quill editor under the hood, you can use the `disable()` method: http://beta.quilljs.com/docs/api/#disable

You can get the reference to `quill` editor from the component with:

```
@ViewChild(Editor)
editor:Editor; // "Editor" is the prime-ng class definition
```

And create a method like:

```
myMethod() {
    this.editor.quill.disable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP has asked for `disabled`, but if anyone is looking for `readonly` the editor acceptes `[readonly]` attribute.

eg:

```
<p-editor formControlName="desctiption" [style]="{'height':'120px'}" [readonly]="disable"></p-editor>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[readonly]** attribute of p-editor and force it by **true** .
example:

```
 <p-editor formControlName="desctiption" [style]="{'height':'120px'}"
 [readonly]="true"></p-editor>
```